# Addressing a multi-dimensional array of objects in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Extreme newbie Swift syntax question...

Trying to address a multidimensional array of UIImageView objects and getting the error

> Cannot subscript a value of type [[UIImageView]] with an index of
>   type UInt32.

I thought I was creating an NxN array of UIImageView objects but I guess not?

Thanks All!

```
func loadDefaultImages()
{
    var pictures : [[UIImageView]] = [];
    let MaxRows: UInt32 = 4
    let MaxCols: UInt32 = 4
    var row: UInt32
    var col: UInt32

    for (row = 0; row <= MaxRows; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col <= MaxCols; col++)
        {
            var newImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "first"))
            pictures[row][col] = UIImageView() /* Error on this statement */

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you need to use `UInt32`?

Comment: You cant use UInt32 as index. You need to change it to Int

Comment: Are you sure the error says Int32 instead of UInt32?

Comment: Leo - you are correct about the solution required Int (and the error did say UInt32, edited to fix above). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, your `pictures` array will not contain any elements, (i.e. it will evaluate to `[]`). As you try to set `pictures[0][0]`, you're trying to reference both a row and column that do not exist yet.

Instead, you could build up the array as you go, like this:

```
func loadDefaultImages() {

    var pictures : [[UIImageView]] = [];
    let MaxRows: UInt32 = 4
    let MaxCols: UInt32 = 4

    for _ in 0..<MaxRows {
        var aRow : [UIImageView] = []
        for _ in 0..<MaxCols {
            let newImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "first"))
            aRow.append(newImage)
        }
        pictures.append(aRow)
    }
}
```

However, a neater way to do this would be to create the array with a default size using the `count, repeatedValue` function, like so:

```
func loadDefaultImages() {

    let MaxRows: Int = 4
    let MaxCols: Int = 4

    var pictures = [[UIImageView?]](count: MaxRows, repeatedValue: [UIImageView?](count: MaxCols, repeatedValue: nil))

    for row in 0..<MaxRows {
        for col in 0..<MaxCols {
            let newImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "first"))
            pictures[row][col] = newImage
        }
    }
}
```